# xml parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Hi Guys 
I would like to parse the following xml string in C#
i tried reading the entire string into the dataset and then using it .. there are simply no tables in the dataset.

here is the xml that I am interested to parse.

xml code is here 
http://pastebin.com/VfT2wAwY

C# code is here 
http://pastebin.com/iwqDK2S6

---

Thanks and regards, 
Gagan Janjua

Comment: What dataset? Can you post your code? And if you're going to paste XML into your question please paste it as text, not as an image.

Comment: i tried pasting that as text, but couldnt do it... i know i am being stupid...!! :(

Comment: If you want to paste it as text, you have to replace the < symbol with &lt; otherwise it thinks you're posting html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change Scott's code to make it work by changing the following line of code:

```
   // I can now access each case specifically
    var allEvents = currentCase.Descendants("events");
```

Make it:

```
   // I can now access each case specifically
    var allEvents = currentCase.Descendants("event");
```

Doing that you have access to each event element. And from there you can definitely have access to ixBugEvent element.

I hope this helps.

P.s.: Sorry to make this another answer, but I would like to highlight the code, and it seems the only way to do it...

Comment: had so much fun today ... flu is gone and the code works .. thanks Wagner. Marked it as an answer.. Thanks to  Scott as well..

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered [LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)?  If you're using .NET Framework 3.5 or later, then LINQ can save you a lot of time.

I haven't tested this, but you could do something like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\mydocument.xml");

var allCases = doc.Element("response").Element("cases").Descendants("case");

foreach (var currentCase in allCases) {
    // I can now access each case specifically
    var allEvents = currentCase.Descendants("events");

    foreach (var currentEvent in allEvents) {
        // now I can access each event
        int ixBugEvent = (int)currentEvent.Element("ixBugEvent");
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: If this works, that would be awesome... however i will test it as soon as i reach home so that i can remote in..... :|

Comment: nope this does not work .. gives me this message "System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element
  Source=System.Xml.Linq
  ParamName=element

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) from System.Xml?

There is no schema in XML that you have provided, so you cannot expect that you can use it to populate DataSet... Unless you define your own schema, that is.

Comment: You don't need to have schema, DataSet can build it automatically.
set.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.Auto) <-- reader is StringReader contains xml in form of string.

Comment: @Dmitry... that is why i was using the dataset.i dont have to worry about the schema in this case... but when i try the dataset way, I am getting a database which is nulll......

Comment: What do you mean database was null? Was dataset null or you didn't get any datatables? Could you please provide us with xml and code?

Comment: sorry i meant dataset :) .. typo .. my bad

Comment: @Paweł Dyda was right, you need a schema. "ixBugEvent" in the xml is both a node and an attribute. P.S. You can use ugly hack (just as quick fix, not more), and replace attribute name in xml before pass it to reader: xmlString = xmlString.Replace("ixBugEvent=", "ixBugEventAttr=");

Answer (score 2):

Your code is returning null because of your catch is making it null. It hits the catch, with the following error:

```
Column name 'ixBugEvent' is defined for different mapping types.
```

I have the impression that the reason for it is that you have ixBugEvent as both an attribute and a element

```
<event ixBugEvent='3' ixBug='2'>
          <ixBugEvent>3</ixBugEvent>
```

Removing one of them fix the issue. The code is working, but your xml schema cannot be translated to a dataset.

Comment: nopes. i cannot change the xml because, i am getting it back from the fogbugz api ....

Comment: wll give this code a try , before this virus downs me .. thanks for all ur help , guys ... every intended help was appreciated